# java - How to compare two objects that might be null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

I need to be able to compare two variables, which might at some times be null. If they're both null, I still want it to be considered equal. Is there any appropriate way to do this?

I was testing it out in NetBeans, and looking at the documentation for .equals(), and saw that null references behave weirdly.

These are my examples and results:

```
Object a = null, b = null;
System.out.println(a == b);
```

returns true.

OR:

```
System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

throws NullPointerException.

Does == work how I want it to in this case, or am I just 'getting lucky' here and it came to the conclusion 'true' for some other reason?

The NullPointerException is also confusing me, as I always understood Object's equals method to be a reference equality. The documentation repeatedly states 'non-null' Objects, but why would that matter for a reference comparison? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Objects.equals(a,b);

Comment: Objects aren't `null`. You need to start differentiating between variables, references, and objects.

Comment: @OP: The answers you've received will help you understand what went wrong.  But after you understand all that, you'll want to pay attention to what Hubert suggested, which is exactly what you are after.

Comment: null is not an object, or an instance. it does not have a class, you can't call methods on it, or use it for anything (except things that actually handle null). null is always equal to null, in the sense of `==`. `equals` on null does not make sense, because it means *these 2 **instances** are the same in a functional sense*

Comment: @njzk2 this reminds me a passage about love from the bible. :)

Answer (score 10):

The `==` operator tests whether two variables have identical value. For object references, this means that the variables must refer to the same object (or both variables must be `null`). The `equals()` method, of course, requires that the variable on which it is invoked not be `null`. It's behavior depends on the type of object being referenced (on the actual object, not on the declared type). The default behavior (defined by `Object`) is to simply use `==`.

To get the behavior you want, you can do:

```
System.out.println(a == null ? b == null : a.equals(b));
```

NOTE: as of Java 7, you can use:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Objects.equals(a, b));
```

which does the same thing internally.

Answer (score 1):

`a.equals(b)` returns a NullPointerException because it's literally

`null.equals(...)`

and null doesn't have a .equals (or any other method).

same thing with `b.equals(a)`

`a == b` returns true because it's `null == null` (obviously true).  So to compare you have to check `a` and `b` for null or something like...

```
if (a != null) 
   return a.equals(b);  // This works because a is not null.  `a.equals(null)` is valid.  
else if (b != null) 
   return b.equals(a);  // a is null, but b is not
else 
   return a == b;
```

the ?: operator is a bit more concise for this

Comment: I don't think you need to test for `b != null`. All you need at that point is to return `true` if `b == null`. No sane implementation of `equals()` will return `true` if the argument is `null` (and `a` _must_ be `null` in that branch). If it does, then it would have to return `true` for all arguments, since the contract for `Object#equals` is that it must implement an equivalence relation.

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  I wrote the extra if statement for completeness in my example... even if it's extraneous

Answer (score 1):

You cannot invoke a method like equals on null value. If you want use a method saftly you must check null value like

```
if(a!=null)
    System.out.println(a.equals(b));
else
    System.out.println(a==b));
```